# Discord.jsV13 MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi i trying to add a embed to a message using Distube, and i get this errors.

```
 An error encountered: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
```

this is my command event:

```
client.distube
  .on('playSong', (queue, song) => {
    queue.textChannel.send({embeds: [
        new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Started Playing')
            .setDescription(`[${song.name}](${song.url})`)
            .addField('**Views:**', song.views, false)
            .addField('**Duration:**', song.formattedDuration, false)
            .addField('**Status**', status(queue), false)
            .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
            .setColor("BLUE")
    ]})
  })
```

I using this packages:
Discord.js@v13
Distube@3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that there is an empty, undefined or null parameter in `.addField()`

Verify each second parameter, and set default value =/= ""

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `song.views`, `status(queue)` and `song.formattedDuration` aren't strings, you could surround them with quotes like so:

```js
client.distube
  .on('playSong', (queue, song) => {
    queue.textChannel.send({embeds: [
        new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Started Playing')
            .setDescription(`[${song.name}](${song.url})`)
            .addField('**Views:**', `${song.views}`, false)
            .addField('**Duration:**', `${song.formattedDuration}`, false)
            .addField('**Status**', `${status(queue)}`, false)
            .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
            .setColor("BLUE")
    ]})
  })
```

An alternative would be to use [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) instead